# low sound levels on toshiba satellite

Tags: sound, volume-control

I just started using Ubuntu 14.04 and am very new to it.

My Toshiba satellite laptop had loud sound volume using Windows. Now, the sound is barely audible in all cases except while playing CDs.

I tried everything I dared on Ubuntu's help sites, but to no avail.
Please help me as this is not the first post I'm trying to create here. All older ones got rejected for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You've a speaker icon on the screen probably near the clock. That location is dependent on the desktop you use.
Click on that icon and a popup will show with sliders in it. Check the setting of the sliders. If they're all up then there's something wrong with your audio settings and then we'll have to look at those.